# utilize SSH command (either -L or -D) to cover a range of ports in tunnel config

Tags: unix, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

All - First off, this may not be possible, but I thought I would try. Our company security is such that we utilize linux bastions to ssh tunnel to segmented networks. It is nice from the desktop (as opposed to Windows bastions) because we can run from Putty and have the term session in the background and sites are accessible via standard browser/apps. In short, we add 127 (loopback) versions of the endpoints to our local host files on our machines, then launch a batch file that launches the linux bastion and has local host/port to remote host/port mappings. So far so good.

Example (hosts file)
127.22.22.22 website.com # real IP would be 10.22.22.22
Example (batch file mapping, for port 443 in this example)
-L 127.22.22.22:443:10.22.22.22:443

Now, we have a new application that we can reach, but as part of login logic, it picks a random port from a range (1000 range in the random ports). These always go to the same remote host port (that is known, for example 18501). Is there a way to map from a range locally to a single port on the remote side? And is it made even more hard by the fact that we are already technically mapping them with the loopback step (if that makes any sense). Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Any ideas? Appreciate any suggestions...